# How Cassandra read works with single column datamodel partition in multiple SSTables?

Tags: cassandra

We use a very simple key-value datamodel in Cassandra, and our partition key is in 17 SSTables. I would like to understand how read works in our concrete case.

If I undestand correctly, general Cassandra reads will need to search for the newest version of each column in the memtable and in different SSTables, until it retrieves all columns and merges them.

Since SSTables are sorted by time, and our data-model is single-column, Ideally our read operations should just hit the newest SSTable containing our partition key since this will contain the whole data.

Will our read operations hit the 17 SSTables? or just the newest one containing the searched partition key?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what version of cassandra you're using, but this is a great talk by Tyler Hobbs on the [read path internals](https://youtu.be/HuDJBTPdaOA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra will search all of them as it isn't sure which columns exist where (DML occurs at the cell level and because of that, variants can exist where reconciliation is performed). Reads are done at the partition level. However, Cassandra can filter out sstables if it knows the partition key doesn't exist in certain ones. That's why compaction is important for optimal reads - to remove the unnecessary cells.

Comment: Thank you, what if we specify the name of the colum in the query? I mean, shouldn't it just retrieve the last update on that column?

Comment: Cassandra doesn't have that information. It simply knows that the partition key is X and it exists in Y sstables. Scan them , reconcile and respond. You can do a simple test: insert into table, flush the table, insert the same row into the same table, flush the table, then query the table. What you'll see is it scans and merges 2 sstables. Partitions are scanned for sstables that contain them.

Answer (score 1):

> Will our read operations hit the 17 SSTables? or just the newest one containing the searched partition key?

To add to Jim's answer, Cassandra has something called a bloom filter for this.  Essentially, it's a probabilistic structure that can tell you one of two things:

- The SSTable *might* contain the data requested.

  **OR**
- The SSTable definitely does *not* contain the data requested.

This should prevent Cassandra from having to scan all 17 SSTables.  My advice would be to run a query with `TRACING ON` in cqlsh, and it'll tell you just how many SSTables it needed to look through.